# Count the number of object in an array in JS

Tags: javascript

```
"abc":[{"a":"a"},{"b":"b"},{"c":"c"}];
```

I got this from my ajax's data callback, how can I know there's 3 object in it? I tried .length method but it grave me the wrong number.

Comment: `length` is the right way to do it, there's no reason that wouldn't work

Comment: Post the code that you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Using .length on the array will give you the correct answer 3, but most likely you're doing data.length which is wrong in your case.

`data["abc"].length` will yield correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code you will get 3 in console :

```
<script>
var test = {"abc":[{"a":"a"},{"b":"b"},{"c":"c"}]};
console.log("Length :"+test.abc.length);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt matter if you have objects in your array or other elements, `array.length` always works on it.

Readup: [Array.length - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)

The code that you have posted, it looks like `abc` is a property of an object.

```js
var obj = {
  "abc":[{"a":"a"},{"b":"b"},{"c":"c"}] // semicolon removed
};

alert(obj.abc.length); // compute length/number of objects here
```

Answer (score 0):

[Array.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) will give you the number of elements in the array.

Your example

`([{"a":"a"},{"b":"b"},{"c":"c"}].length == 3) // => true`

So your issue lies elsewhere.